# How to fix this issue “Dummy Output” for Output device section and I can’t select any device in the “Input Device” section?

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-20.04

Please note that the sound isn’t muted I’m using Ubuntu 20.04 focal

I have tried the following solution:
Restart PulseAudio:

```
Open a terminal window (you can use Ctrl + Alt + T).
Type the following command and press Enter:

pulseaudio -k
```

Check Sound Settings:

```
Click on the volume icon in the top-right corner of the screen.
Select "Sound Settings".
Ensure that the correct output device is selected. Sometimes, it might be set to "Dummy Output" mistakenly (but it's the only option available).
```

Update Audio Drivers:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade

Reboot the system after the update completes.
```

Reset ALSA:

```
sudo alsa force-reload
```

Check System Logs:

```
Open a terminal window and type:

dmesg | grep snd
```